# モジュール内でinternalを使用しているクラスをカスタマイズしたい

Tags: swift, ios

[`Charts`](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)というフレームワークを使っています。Cocoapodsでインストールしました。

この中で`RadarChartView`の表示を変えたいと思います。そのためには`RadarChartRenderer`を変更する必要があります。

`RadarChartView`の中では

```
internal override func initialize()
{
    super.initialize()

    _yAxis = YAxis(position: .left)

    renderer = RadarChartRenderer(chart: self, animator: _animator, viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler)

    _yAxisRenderer = YAxisRendererRadarChart(viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler, yAxis: _yAxis, chart: self)
    _xAxisRenderer = XAxisRendererRadarChart(viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler, xAxis: _xAxis, chart: self)

    self.highlighter = RadarHighlighter(chart: self)
}
```

の`renderer`が`RadarChartRenderer`のインスタンスです。まず`initialize`がinternal指定なのでこれをオーバーライドすることはできません。`renderer`は

```
open class ChartViewBase: NSUIView, ChartDataProvider, AnimatorDelegate
{
    ...

    /// object responsible for rendering the data
    open var renderer: DataRenderer?

    ...
}
```

ですのでopenですからカスタムのrendererに置き換えることはできそうです。ただし

```
    renderer = RadarChartRenderer(chart: self, animator: _animator, viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler)
```

で使われる`_animator`や`_viewPortHandler`がinternalですので必要なパラメータを`RadarChartView`のサブクラスやextensionで与えることはできません。

このような疑問は私だけでなく多くの人が持っているようで

- [Module is not extensible](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/357)
- [ChartUtils methods are marked internal and cannot be use to create custom charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1518)

ほか色々あります。2015年のプルリクエストなのでこれが採用される見込みはないのかも知れません。

何か上手いアイディアがあればお知恵を拝借したいと思います。よろしくお願いします。

現在はモジュールを直接書き換えるという乱暴な方法を取っています。

## 追記（2017年2月7日）

具体的に何をしたいか書かなかったためわかりにくかったかも知れません。

レーダーチャートで一番凹んでいるところに「！」を付与してほしいと上司から頼まれました。例えば試験の成績をレーダーチャートで表して、英語が一番点が低かったらそこに「！」を表示します。

そのためには`RadarChartRenderer`を変更するしかなく、カスタムの`RadarChartRenderer`を使うには`RadarChartView`のrendererも変更しないといけないのです。

Chartsライブラリはクラス全体はopenになっているものの、internal指定も多く実質的にカスタマイズが難しい構造になっています。

Comment: こういう場合、元のプロジェクトをForkして編集し、CocoapodsではForkしたものを指定する方法がよく使われると思いますが・・・　そういうレベルではなくて、もっと根本的な解決方法をお探しでしょうか？

Comment: はい、以前は元のプロジェクトをforkしてcocoapodsでそれを指定していました。この度、Swift 3に移行したため、Chartsも2.xから3になりました。ライブラリがアップデートされる度にforkし直してまたコードを直すというのは煩雑なので改善したかったのです。自分のプロジェクト内にサブクラスを持っていればライブラリの更新も簡単になります。

Answer (score 0):

「RadarChartRendererを変更」は私では無理ですが根っこの問題である表示を変えたいということに対して一例として回答してみます。

Charts Ver 3.0.1

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var radarChartView: RadarChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let titles = ["コーヒー", "紅茶", "ココア", "ほうじ茶", "緑茶", "玄米茶", "プーアール茶", "ごぼう茶", "はとむぎ茶"]
    var entries1 = [RadarChartDataEntry]()
    var entries2 = [RadarChartDataEntry]()

   //味や人気の点数
    for _ in 0...titles.count {
        let double1 = 80.0
        let double2 = 20.0
        let entry1 = RadarChartDataEntry(value: double1)
        let entry2 = RadarChartDataEntry(value: double2)
        entries1.append(entry1)
        entries2.append(entry2)
    }

    let set1 = RadarChartDataSet(values: entries1, label: "味")
    set1.colors = [UIColor.white]

    let set2 = RadarChartDataSet(values: entries2, label: "人気")
    set2.drawFilledEnabled = true
    set2.valueColors = [UIColor.blue]
    set2.fillColor = UIColor.white

    //目盛りだったり線だったり描写されるものは色々と消せます
    set2.drawValuesEnabled = false

    let data = RadarChartData(dataSets: [set1, set2])
    radarChartView.data = data

    radarChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    //Ver 3.0から軸のタイトルの付け方が変わったようです
    radarChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: titles)

    //点の最大値と最小値
    radarChartView.yAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    radarChartView.yAxis.axisMaximum = 100

    radarChartView.minOffset = 64

    radarChartView.yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    radarChartView.chartDescription?.text = "単位：点"

    radarChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 3.5)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

バージョンが上がったことで細部が変わっているのでその点には注意してください。
これをビルドすると
[image: ビルド画像]
こうなります。
答えられる範囲で回答してみましたがいかがでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。コードを見たところ、axisなどにオプションを指定しているようですね。具体的に書かなかったのですが（追記します）、やりたいこと一例は、レーダーチャートで一番凹んでいる箇所に「！」マークを付けたいのです。そのためには`RadarChartRenderer`を変更するしかなく、カスタムの`RadarChartRenderer`を使うには`RadarChartView`のrendererも変更しないといけないのです。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。どうも僕の回答は趣旨が違っていたようですね。お力になれずに申し訳ないです。